# Read next lines of a file to determine whether or not to print current line

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to write this program slicer program in python, but this little bit is taking me forever to figure out.

I want to read certain file line by line and only print the lines that affect a certain variable.
In this case `num`

this is the text file I'm reading from:

```
a = 3
b = 4
num = 0

while a > b:
    if a > b:
        a = a +2
        b = b + 1

        if a > 2:
            num-=1
```

My python file that has to read this file ^ and it has to isolate the variable `num` by printing the lines that contain the variable `num` and the loop statements where `num` is inside.
This is the output I expect:

```
num = 0

while a > b:
    if a > b:
        if a > 2:
            num-=1
```

This is my code so far and the part of the code that is in charge of reading the lines inside the loops is not working:

```
# Open file
    file = open('text.py', 'r')
    Lines = file.readlines()
    count = 0
    word = "num"
    # Store all the loop statements that can appear in the file
    keyword = ["while", "for", "if", "else", "elif", "def"]

    for i in range(len(Lines)):
        count += 1

        # if line contains keyword
        if any(word in Lines[i] for word in keyword):
            # read lines inside the loop
            # count_indent is a function that counts the indent of the line to compare it and see if the line is inside the loop or not. I didn't added to the question shorter
            line_indent = count_indent(Lines[i])+4
            while i <= len(Lines) and count_indent(Lines[i + 1]) == line_indent:

                # if word appears in the next lines that are inside the loop then we print the loop statement
                if word in Lines[i + 1]:
                    print(str(count) + " : " + Lines[i])

                else:
                    break

                # move to next line inside the loop
                i = i + 1


        # If line is not empty and contains word
        if Lines[i] != '\n' and word in Lines[i]:
            print(str(count) + " : " + Lines[i])
```

Comment: Try to read the file making explicit that \n is the line separator  file = open('text.py', 'r', newline = '\n')

Comment: What you want is a proper parser. Look at the `ast` module.

Answer (score 0):

This code output is similar to what you expect.

```
file = open('text.py', 'r', newline = '\n')
lines = file.readlines()
word = "num"
keyword = ["while", "for", "if", "else", "elif", "def"]

with open('out_text.py', 'wt') as fout:
    
    for line in lines:

        if any(word in line for word in keyword):

            fout.write(line + '\n')

        elif word in line:

            fout.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: This kinda works, but if we get a different text file where there is a loop that does not affect the variable we are focusing on at all then it will print it anyways. The goal is to print the loop statements that affect the variable `num`. Thanks a lot for your response anyways, I appreciate it

Comment: I have modified it, instead of printing the lines, it creates an output file.